# closing and removeData not working in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I used jquery 1.12.2  and Bootstrap 3.

Here is my code,

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '#wideModal', function () {
    $('#wideModal .modal-body').empty();
    $('#wideModal .modal-content').removeData('bs.modal');
    $('#wideModal .modal-body').html("");
    $('#wideModal').data('bs.modal', null);
});
```

It still not deleting the content of the previous modal.
I can't use option.remote.
To place data to my modal, i used JavaScript.

Here is the code,

```
$('#wideModal .modal-body').html(str);
```

How to completely remove content of the modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to empty input fields you can try this

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('.modal-body').find('textarea,input').val('');
});
```

Comment: I dont have input fields

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery site](https://api.jquery.com/removeData/) says 
The .removeData() method allows us to remove values that were previously set using .data().

I think just .remove() should work, as it removes matched elements from DOM.